# GnuPG 2.0.27 Make Failure

Tags: compiling, error-handling

Does anyone know what this means at the end of a GnuPG 'make" command:

```
mv -f .deps/libcommon_a-signal.Tpo .deps/libcommon_a-signal.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I../gl -I../intl -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DGNUPG_BINDIR="\"/usr/local/bin\"" -DGNUPG_LIBEXECDIR="\"/usr/local/libexec\"" -DGNUPG_LIBDIR="\"/usr/local/lib/gnupg\"" -DGNUPG_DATADIR="\"/usr/local/share/gnupg\"" -DGNUPG_SYSCONFDIR="\"/usr/local/etc/gnupg\""       -I/home/normal-user/NORMALUSER/DOWNLOADS/GNUPG/include -I/usr/local/include -I/home/normal-user/NORMALUSER/DOWNLOADS/GNUPG/include -I/usr/local/include -I/home/normal-user/NORMALUSER/DOWNLOADS/GNUPG/include -I/usr/local/include -I/home/normal-user/NORMALUSER/DOWNLOADS/GNUPG/include -DWITHOUT_GNU_PTH=1 -g -O2 -Wall -Wno-pointer-sign -Wpointer-arith -Wno-psabi -MT libcommon_a-estream.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcommon_a-estream.Tpo -c -o libcommon_a-estream.o `test -f 'estream.c' || echo './'`estream.c
mv -f .deps/libcommon_a-estream.Tpo .deps/libcommon_a-estream.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I../gl -I../intl -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DGNUPG_BINDIR="\"/usr/local/bin\"" -DGNUPG_LIBEXECDIR="\"/usr/local/libexec\"" -DGNUPG_LIBDIR="\"/usr/local/lib/gnupg\"" -DGNUPG_DATADIR="\"/usr/local/share/gnupg\"" -DGNUPG_SYSCONFDIR="\"/usr/local/etc/gnupg\""       -I/home/normal-user/NORMALUSER/DOWNLOADS/GNUPG/include -I/usr/local/include -I/home/normal-user/NORMALUSER/DOWNLOADS/GNUPG/include -I/usr/local/include -I/home/normal-user/NORMALUSER/DOWNLOADS/GNUPG/include -I/usr/local/include -I/home/normal-user/NORMALUSER/DOWNLOADS/GNUPG/include -DWITHOUT_GNU_PTH=1 -g -O2 -Wall -Wno-pointer-sign -Wpointer-arith -Wno-psabi -MT libcommon_a-estream-printf.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcommon_a-estream-printf.Tpo -c -o libcommon_a-estream-printf.o `test -f 'estream-printf.c' || echo './'`estream-printf.c
mv -f .deps/libcommon_a-estream-printf.Tpo .deps/libcommon_a-estream-printf.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I../gl -I../intl -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DGNUPG_BINDIR="\"/usr/local/bin\"" -DGNUPG_LIBEXECDIR="\"/usr/local/libexec\"" -DGNUPG_LIBDIR="\"/usr/local/lib/gnupg\"" -DGNUPG_DATADIR="\"/usr/local/share/gnupg\"" -DGNUPG_SYSCONFDIR="\"/usr/local/etc/gnupg\""       -I/home/normal-user/NORMALUSER/DOWNLOADS/GNUPG/include -I/usr/local/include -I/home/normal-user/NORMALUSER/DOWNLOADS/GNUPG/include -I/usr/local/include -I/home/normal-user/NORMALUSER/DOWNLOADS/GNUPG/include -I/usr/local/include -I/home/normal-user/NORMALUSER/DOWNLOADS/GNUPG/include -DWITHOUT_GNU_PTH=1 -g -O2 -Wall -Wno-pointer-sign -Wpointer-arith -Wno-psabi -MT libcommon_a-audit.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcommon_a-audit.Tpo -c -o libcommon_a-audit.o `test -f 'audit.c' || echo './'`audit.c
In file included from audit.c:28:0:
audit.h:23:18: fatal error: ksba.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ksba.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [libcommon_a-audit.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/normal-user/Downloads/gnupg-2.0.27/common'
make[1]: *** [check] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/normal-user/Downloads/gnupg-2.0.27/common'
make: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
normal-user@normaluser-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/gnupg-2.0.27$
```

I reinstalled a fresh download of GnuPG 1.0.27 in the hopes that I had corrupted the old one with repeated attempts at install in a different directory, but I got the same error resulting.

Is it possible I corrupted `ksba.h` in another directory?

Comment: The literal meaning of the error is that for some reason the compiler can't find the ksba.h file listed an an include in the code.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't have [`libksba-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=ksba.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any) installed. Install it:

```
sudo apt-get install libksba-dev
```